# How to get value of button with JS

Tags: javascript, button

How can I get the value of a button when there are many multiple buttons created? Currently on my Javascript file I have it so my search history makes a button in a list with a "value" of the city that is labeled.

When I click on the button that was made I get undefined.

```
function recentSearch(city) {
    var addCity = document.createElement("button");
    addCity.setAttribute("value", city);
    addCity.textContent = city;
    document.getElementById("searchHistory").append(addCity);

    cities.push(city);
    localStorage.setItem("searches",JSON.stringify(cities));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will log the value of the button to the console when it is clicked.

```js
function recentSearch(city) {
    var addCity = document.createElement("button");
    addCity.setAttribute("value", city);
    addCity.textContent = city;
    addCity.onclick = (e)=>{
        console.log(e.target.getAttribute('value'));
        //or whatever other code you want to do onclick
    }
    document.getElementById("searchHistory").append(addCity);

    cities.push(city);
    localStorage.setItem("searches",JSON.stringify(cities));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding so many buttons use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). Add one listener to the parent container, add your buttons, and then, in the listener function, check to see if the clicked element is a button, and log its value.

```js
const searchHistory = document.querySelector('#searchHistory');

// Add one listener to the container that calls `handleClick`
searchHistory.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {

  // Destructure the nodeName and value from
  // the clicked element, and log the value if the
  // element is a button
  const { nodeName, value } = e.target;
  if (nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
    console.log(value);
  }
}

function recentSearch(city) {
  var addCity = document.createElement('button');
  addCity.value = city;
  addCity.textContent = city;
  searchHistory.append(addCity);
}

const cities = ['London', 'Rome', 'New York', 'Seoul', 'Kingston'];

for (const city of cities) {
  recentSearch(city);
}
```

```html
<div id="searchHistory"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). They make your code easier to read and provide a great way to pass along data inside of elements - and you can access their data using `element.dataset.<attribute_name>` - in this case `e.target.dataset.value` (from within the buttons click listener).

```js
cities = []

function recentSearch(city) {
  // FOR DEMO ONLY::
  if (!city) city = "city " + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000);

  var addCity = document.createElement("button");
  addCity.setAttribute("data-value", city);
  addCity.textContent = city;
  addCity.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(`my city is: ${e.target.dataset.value}`);
  })
  document.getElementById("searchHistory").append(addCity);
  

  cities.push(city);
  // localStorage.setItem("searches",JSON.stringify(cities));
}
```

```html
<div id='searchHistory'>
</div>
<button onclick='recentSearch()'>Make City</button>
```

Comment: Buttons have [a value attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-value).

Comment: @Andy - too right, thanks